# Image is stretching while capturing video using mediarecorder

Tags: android-camera

I have made an application in which I am capturing video using MediaRecorder.But when preview starts on device it seems that image is stretching I just gone through all the related question here or on google but didn't get success.Here is my code.

video.xml

```
<SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/camera_view"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
```

Video.java file configuration

```
public void startRecording() {

    try {
        if(some codition){
                // recording call.
                setCameraDisplayOrientaion();

                camera.unlock();
                mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
                mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mediaRecorder
                        .setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);

                mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
                mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);

                CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P == CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH
                        || CamcorderProfile
                                .hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P) ? CamcorderProfile
                        .get(cameraId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P)
                        : CamcorderProfile.get(cameraId,
                                CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
                profile.videoFrameRate = 15;
                profile.videoBitRate = 150000;
                profile.audioBitRate = 12200;
                mediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);
                mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(string);

                mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
                try {
                    mediaRecorder.prepare();
                    mediaRecorder.start();



                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(ResponseActivity.class.toString(), e.getMessage());
                    releaseMediaRecorder();
                }


        } else {
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            setCameraDisplayOrientaion();

            camera.unlock();
            mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
            mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);

            mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
            mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);

        CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P == CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH
                    || CamcorderProfile
                            .hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P) ? CamcorderProfile
                    .get(cameraId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P)
                    : CamcorderProfile.get(cameraId,
                            CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
            profile.videoFrameRate = videoFrameRate;
            profile.videoBitRate = videoBitrate;
            profile.audioBitRate = audioBitrate;
            mediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);

            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(fullQuestionPath);

            mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
            try {
                mediaRecorder.prepare();
                mediaRecorder.start();



            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(ResponseActivity.class.toString(), e.getMessage());
                releaseMediaRecorder();
            }


        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Please let me know that what configuration need to change here,Any help would be appreciable.